# How to invalidate a session and block the access when click on browsers back button?

Tags: java, jsp, session

I am writing JSP a page, at the time of logout I invalidate the session.but the problem is when I click back I can visit the previous page. How to avoid it. After I made some internet searching i got to know that it is because cache of the browser. Can any one help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly set response header and let browser know not to cache those pages.

Set response header as below for all jsp pages which should not be shown on click of back button.:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate");
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```

Or even better approach would be to set `noCacheFilter` to prevent caching of jsp pages by setting a filter for *.jsp files like below :

```
@Override
public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setDateHeader("Expiresponse", 0);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

and add this filter to map `*.jsp` files li

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>noCacheFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.abcd.NoCacheFilter</filter-class> //Filter class path
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>noCacheFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Then What happens when I click on back button? and you are saying that I hav to include this every jsp which dont want to cache. but when we logged in we want to browse many other page , and I have sign out in many pages. I want only at the time of sign out i dont want to give access of previous page insted wanted to display messege "login again"

Comment: By adding those above response header, you will not face an issue of back button page loading and to redirect to login page again, you have to manage it in your login filter or something whatever you have used to authenticate user

Comment: Thanks dude . . it seems to work for me , pls tell me about how to map filter for all jsp.

Comment: Answer updated and do close the question if this answer solve your problem :)